# Problem with accessing in DOM with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, dom, callback, jsonp

I changed the tree of my JSON-P output, and i cannot access to my object DOM anymore :

Here's my output :

```
jsonp1271634374310(
{"Inter-Medias":
    {"name":"Inter-Medias","idGSP":"14","average":"80","services":"8.86"}
});
```

And here's my jQuery script :

```
success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
widget = data.name;
widget += data.average ;
....
```

1. I know one level is missing, but if I try to do : `data.Inter-Medias.name` or `data.name.name`
   it's still not working. 
   **Any idea please ?**

Thank you.

Comment: If you feel the need to "Bonus question" it's almost always better to either search first ( ;) ) or start a second question. Asking two questions in one post becomes confusing in the long run.

Comment: sorry, i'll stop asking 3 questions + bonus question :D in my posts ;). Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing but I think what your issue is the JSON key. Try doing this:

```
data["Inter-Medias"].name
```

Now if you are expecting multiple objects you want the root element in your JSON to be an array.

```
[
    {
        "name" : "A",
        "average" : 1
    },
    {
        "name" : "B",
        "average" : 2
    }
]
```

In code you can access it like this.

```
var obj = null, length = data.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    obj = data[i];
    if (obj.name === "A") {
        runningAverage += obj.average;
    }    
}
```

Comment: sorry if my questions were confusing, you were right but i gave the case where i know that the result would be "Inter-Medias" but what i put for the general cases where it would work for everything please ?